# F# Making the result of an async workflow available to be displayed by the UI thread

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, f#, window

I'm trying to launch a window which will require waiting for a login to an external system, so I would like to handle this login asynchronously. I've achieved this in the F# interactive window and everything behaves as expected, however when I run the code in my program I get the error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

F# Interactive:

```
#r "WindowsBase"
#r "PresentationCore"
#r "PresentationFramework"

open System
open System.Threading
open System.Windows

let loginTask = async {
    Console.WriteLine "Logging in"
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    let user = "MyUser"
    Console.WriteLine ("Logged in as " + user)
    return user
}

let createWindow () =
    Console.WriteLine "Creating window"
    let window = Window()
    window.Title <- "MyWindow"
    window.Show()
    window

let runWindowWithUser (window:Window) user =
    window.Title <- (user + "'s Window")
    Console.WriteLine ("Running " + window.Title + " as " + user)

let mainAsync = async {
    let window = createWindow()

    let! userToken = loginTask |> Async.StartChild
    let! user = userToken 

    runWindowWithUser window user
    }

do mainAsync |> Async.StartImmediate
```

Program.fs

```
open System.Threading
open System.Windows

[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main argv =

    let loginTask = async {
        Console.WriteLine "Logging in"
        Thread.Sleep(5000)
        let user = "MyUser"
        Console.WriteLine ("Logged in as " + user)
        return user
    }
    
    let createWindow () =
        Console.WriteLine "Creating window"
        let window = Window()
        window.Title <- "MyWindow"
        window.Show()
        window
    
    let runWindowWithUser (window:Window) user =
        window.Title <- (user + "'s Window")
        Console.WriteLine ("Running " + window.Title + " as " + user)
    
    let mainAsync = async {
        let window = createWindow()
    
        let! userToken = loginTask |> Async.StartChild
        let! user = userToken 
    
        runWindowWithUser window user
        }
    
    do mainAsync |> Async.StartImmediate

    Console.ReadKey()

    1
```

I understand that `let!` can cause the rest of the workflow to continue on the background thread so I have tried swapping threads:

```
    let mainAsync = async {
        let context = SynchronizationContext.Current
        let window = createWindow()
    
        do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
        let! user = loginTask
        
        do! Async.SwitchToContext context
        runWindowWithUser window user
    }
```

but this doesn't seem to change back to the original thread as I'm expecting.

I also tried to keep all of my UI code out of the async workflow to avoid dealing with threads, but then I'm unsure of how to get my `user` information back from work which is done on a background thread

```
let loginTask = async {
    Console.WriteLine "Logging in"
    Thread.Sleep(5000)
    let user = "MyUser"
    Console.WriteLine ("Logged in as " + user)
    return user
}

Console.WriteLine "Creating window"
let window = Window()
window.Title <- "MyWindow"
window.Show()

let user = loginTask|> Async.StartImmediate   // How do I get user information from loginTask without using let! that must be called from an async workflow?

window.Title <- (user + "'s Window")
Console.WriteLine ("Running " + window.Title + " as " + user)
```

I'm very new to F# and functional programming in general. How am I able to get the `user` information from the login code on a background thread into the UI thread, and also why is the threading behavior different in the F# interactive window?

Comment: The message means just what it says, a UI object can only be accessed on the thread it was created on. So, why do you want to open a window on another thread? Why not open a window on the main thread, get the login info from the user, then pass that to another thread for asynchronous processing?

Comment: I don't necessarily want to open the window on a new thread.  I was hoping that creating the window as in my first code block would work because the window was created on the main thread, but by the time the I get the user info, the code is on a different thread and I can no longer update the window (although it doesn't behave this way in the FSI window).  My last code block is my attempt at creating the window outside of an async workflow so that I won't have these thread issues, but I'm not too sure how to get the user info from an asynchronous function doing it that way (the commented line)

Comment: Ah, I just looked closer at your code and realized you're not getting login info from the user, that window is just for the user to see while the login is happening in the background. You're actually on the right track with switching back to the UI thread, let me try this and see what I find...

Comment: So, turns out that SynchronizationContext.Current is null in the main thread, even if you create the window first. This is normally set somewhere by WPF. Any reason why you are doing this program as a console app instead of a Windows application? If I do this as the latter, then SynchronizationContext.Current is not null and everything works as expected.

Comment: I was just doing it as a console app to make printing debugging messages easier because for some reason when I debug in VS on my work computer it restarts (it's as frustrating as it sounds).  I swapped to a Windows application, but it still seems to be null for me so I'll have to do some digging on why that is.  This is helpful though, because I see that if given `null` SwitchToContext is the same as SwitchToThreadPool which is what I was seeing when printing thread IDs, so thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my code, I've removed the Console.Writeline() calls, you would just replace those with logger calls (or Debug.WriteLine(), or whatever).

```
open System
open System.Threading
open System.Windows

let createWindow() =
    let window = Window()
    window.Title <- "MyWindow"
    window.Show()
    window

let runWindowWithUser (window: Window) user =
    window.Title <- (user + "'s Window")

let loginTask = 
    async {
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        let user = "MyUser"
        return user
    }
    
[<EntryPoint; STAThread>]
let main _ =
    let app = Application()
    app.MainWindow <- createWindow()

    app.Startup.Add (fun _ ->
        async {
            let context = SynchronizationContext.Current
            do! Async.SwitchToThreadPool()
            let! user = loginTask
            do! Async.SwitchToContext context
            runWindowWithUser app.MainWindow user
        } |> Async.StartImmediate
    )

    app.Run()
```

Comment: The login portion wasn't running asynchronously, but uncommenting the SwitchToThreadPool line took care of that and now it works like a charm.  Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I got a little careless there and didn't notice it because I had cut the sleep down to 1 second. I'll edit the answer.